# gradle takes one hour online build

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

My app.gradle
It is literally taking more than one hour in online build.
(By online build I mean Gradle offline build unchecked)
In offline build however, it takes around 5-10 mins.
Whenever I want to add new library I will have to build online.

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.licianhorse.management.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                    onesignal_app_id: "df5308f0-b573-4247-ac2f-88924310870f",
                                    onesignal_google_project_number: "523535792051"]
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 //One Signal Dependencies
 //    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
 //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
 //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
 //    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
//One Signal Dependencies

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.13'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.0-beta'
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0"
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
//    compile ('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.1'
//    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
//    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
//    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
//    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-           loader:1.9.3'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile project(":libraries:couchbase-lite-android")
compile project(":libraries:couchbase-lite-java-core")
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably behind a proxy, you might have recently changed your password or something has changed from settings perspective. Go to

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

in **gradle.properties** file, delete/ change **proxy settings**. They are different to your android studio proxy settings.

Had the same issue, gradle used to take an hour to build. After I deleted proxy settings from gragle.properties file, it now takes couple seconds.

Comment: It helped me. Several days ago I used proxy, but then I was not able to remove the config in Android Studio settings. When I removed the proxy from the file, it's building in usual time.

Answer (score 0):

In `Android Studio` go to

```
`File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
```

Check the `'Offline work'` under `'Global Gradle settings'`

It will reduce `gradle build` time a lot.

But if you want to go with new library then only way is to put online work for once at start let it build once, then again check the offline work option.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I already mentioned, it builds good in offline mode, but when I uncheck offline because I want a new library it takes a lot of time.

Comment: https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

try this solution, it is one of the ways.

Comment: Disabling offline work doesn't really help. For instance, I cannot validate, or sync my work to my remote project, can't downloa dependencies etc.